# Java Set and Get variable in other function

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a variable from another function in the same .java file.

This is an example:

```
public static void showWindow(User user)
{
    String checkList = null;

    if (user.getNetConnection().getBonus() >= 0.)
    {
        checkList = "variable1";
    }
    else
    {
        checkList = "variable2";
    }
    showCommunity(user, checkList);
}

private static void loadSingle()
{
    allSingle = new LinkedList<>();
    try (Connection con = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(checkList);
        ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery())...(the rest of funcion here)
```

There is anyway to use the variable **checklist** from function showWindow inside the function loadSingle?

Comment: With php I can do it easy, but I'm newbie in java! Sorry if this is a so easy question!

Comment: Since it's a static method,if checkList is public you could access it by `ClassName.checkList` (although getters/setters are recommended) so its like `ClassName.getCheckList();` considering they are in different class. If its the same class, just `checkList` or `getCheckList()`.

Comment: Yes, just use it. Since the local variable there is called `checkBuffList` and not `checkList` it must be a static variable in class scope, so you can access it in any method.

Comment: Sorry, inside the method, I did wrong with checkBuffList, error is only in the example... sorry for bad example! But I believe with the reply "Declare it outside of the method, this will work. I'm so noob in java!

Comment: in my answer there's a code example of declaring it outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you made was just a typo or what, but you are defining a variable `checkBuffList` which you are never using.

If it is in fact a typo, what you should be able to do is defining a static variable and a getter, like this

```
private static String checkList;

public static String getCheckList(){
    return checkList;
}
```

So if you want to call it from the same class you can simply use `checkList`, but if you need it from an outside class simply call `ClassName.getCheckList()`.

Answer (score 4):

Declare it outside of the method (I'm assuming you meant `checkBuffList`).

Comment: Too bad OP fixed it :D.

Comment: I have fixed it, sorry for the "checkBuffList"!

Comment: This is only one file of that I need to change, I'll learn more about java. I'm using PHP for a few years, but using with procedure and never with oriented object. I don't know why, oriented object does'n enter in my mind. Everyone says "Oriented object is good and easy" but I did so many things to try understand and when I start to understand I always think "Procedure is more easy" and back to procedure again! I need to stop it and learn oriented object!